# maven failsafe plugin

Tags: maven, selenium, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am trying to run only selenium tests using mvn failsafe plugin. I created a separate profile to run only the selenium tests but mvn is not able to find them. my project structure looks like

```
moduleA
  scr/main/...
  src/test/integration/java/...
  scr/test/unit/java/...    

moduleB
  scr/main/...
  src/test/integration/java/...
  scr/test/unit/java/...

moduleC (only for selenium tests)
  scr/main/java/com/selenium/A.java
  src/test/java/...
```

Since I have new directories for the unit and integration tests in moduleA and B. I have defined the following in pom.xml (listingB) to let Maven know about the additional test directories. So far so good but when I add selenium tests in moduleC and I want to run only selenium its not running selenium tests. I created a new profile (listingA) to run selenium tests. Any help is appreciated.

**listingA:**

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>selenium</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>verify</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <includes>
              <include>**/selenium/*.java</include>
            </includes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

**listinB:**

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-test-source</id>
        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-test-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>${basedir}/src/test/unit/java</source>
            <source>${basedir}/src/test/integration/java</source>
            <source>${basedir}/src/test/common/java</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>add-test-resource</id>
        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>${basedir}/src/test/integration/resources</directory>
              <directory>${basedir}/src/test/unit/resources</directory>
              <directory>${basedir}/src/test/common/resources</directory>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Please can you tell us the Maven command you executed to try and run the Selenium tests?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing which came into my mind is why you are separating the unit- and integration tests by using a different folder, cause in Maven the separation between unit- and integration tests is done by naming convention.

The unit tests have to be named like

```
**/Test*.java
**/*Test.java
**/*TestCase.java
```

The integration test have to be named like:

```
**/IT*.java
**/*IT.java
**/*ITCase.java
```

This means in other words you can put your integration tests and your unit tests into the same folder which is **src/test/java** without any problem. The execution of the integration tests is not influenced by this.

If you would call

```
mvn clean package
```

only the unit tests will be run. If you need to run the integration tests as well you can simply use:

```
mvn verify
```

If you wan't to skip the unit tests you can use the following:

mvn -DskipTests=true verify

For the separate selenium module which you have created the best solutin is to put the integration tests into the usual folder **src/test/java** with the appropriate naming convention.

The problem you might have is if your integration tests needed some special resources you might move those integration tests into the separate module with integration tests only.

Comment: I have put the selenium tests in the usual folder src/test/java in the seperate module but problem is maven is not identifying this folder when I run with the new profile. it doesnot run any tests in this new module.

Comment: You shouldn't use profiles for such things, cause maven has a life-cycle phase for integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your Selenium tests are in the `src/test/java` folder, delete the `<includes>` parameter from the configuration of `maven-failsafe-plugin` in **listingA**
2. Name your Selenium test classes like:

   ```
     **/IT*.java
     **/*IT.java
     **/*ITCase.java
   ```

   (as **khmarbaise** has suggested)
3. Failsafe runs integration tests using Surefire, therefore **don't name** your Selenium test classes like:

   ```
   **/Test*.java
   **/*Test.java
   **/*TestCase.java
   ```

   because this will make them run in **test** fase and not in **integration-test** fase as you plan.

I have a configuration similar to yours and it works.